# Entity Framework Core, Stored Procedure

Tags: entity-framework

I am totally confused regarding how to use Stored Procedures using Entity Framework Core. If the stored procedure return an anonymous type, how do I retrieve the data? If the return type is not anonymous, what should I do? How do I add input/output parameters?

I am asking these questions because everywhere I look, I get a different answer. I guess EF Core is evolving rapidly and Microsoft is dabbling with a lot of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I add input/output parameters?

I'm going to answer this particular question of yours.

Below is a TSQL stored procedure with two input and two output parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[yourstoredprocedure] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @varone bigint
    ,@vartwo Date
    ,@varthree double precision OUTPUT
    ,@varfour bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- YOUR CODE HERE
  SET @varthree = 10.02;
  SET @varfour = @varone;
  return;
END
```

Now To execute this stored procedure using Entity Framework Core

```
MyContext.Database
                   .ExecuteSqlCommand(@"EXECUTE [yourstoredprocedure] " +
                                       " {0} " +
                                       ", {1} " +
                                       ",@varthree OUTPUT " +
                                       ", @varfour OUTPUT ", dataOne, dataTwo, outputVarOne, outputVarTwo);


var outputResultOne= outputVarOne.Value as double?;
var outputResultTwo= outputVarTwo.Value as long?;
```

You can pass your input simply using parameterized query as above. You can also create named parameters. such as for output parameters, I've created two named parameters as -

```
var outputVarOne = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@varthree ",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.Double,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
        };
var outputVarTwo = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@varfour ",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int64,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
        };
```

And This is how using EF Core you execute a stored procedure with input and output parameters. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @downvoter I'd really appreciate if your downvote is explained as if there is something i'm doing wrong I'd like to know and correct myself. If downvote is not explained, I'll never know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

This solution provides methods that call a stored procedure and maps the returned value to a defined (non-model) entity. https://github.com/verdie-g/StoredProcedureDotNetCore

Microsoft address this issue:
 "SQL queries can only be used to return entity types that are part of your model. There is an enhancement on our backlog to enable returning ad-hoc types from raw SQL queries." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

And here is the issue tracked in GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1862

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

you might use an extention like [StoredProcedureEFCore](https://github.com/verdie-g/StoredProcedureEFCore)

Then the usage is more intuitively.

List rows = null;

```
ctx.LoadStoredProc("dbo.ListAll")
   .AddParam("limit", 300L)
   .AddParam("limitOut", out IOutParam<long> limitOut)
   .Exec(r => rows = r.ToList<Model>());

long limitOutValue = limitOut.Value;

ctx.LoadStoredProc("dbo.ReturnBoolean")
   .AddParam("boolean_to_return", true)
   .ReturnValue(out IOutParam<bool> retParam)
   .ExecNonQuery();

bool b = retParam.Value;

ctx.LoadStoredProc("dbo.ListAll")
   .AddParam("limit", 1L)
   .ExecScalar(out long l);
```